# How to generate Google Map with dynamic address?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a Google Map with a dynamic address from ajax method. These are codes:

```
Controller

var la;
var lo;

var map;

function createMap() {

    la= setLatitude();
    lo= setLongitude();
    var centerCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(la, lo); //dyanmic address through ajax
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: centerCoord,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('User-Map'),mapOptions);
    function sayHello(){alert('hahahhaha');}
}

function setLatitude(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'geo-data',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
           return  data['latitude'];
        }
    });
}

function setLongitude(){
    return 145.008062;
}
```

However, it does not work. Google Map always initializes the map before I can get the coordinates from ajax.

Anyone knows why and how can I generate a Google Map with dynamic address?

Comment: have you tried adding `async: 'true'` to the ajax settings?

Comment: You can try `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {....});` instead of the `createMap() {...}` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling **return  data['latitude'];** from the **success** does not mean that it will be the return value of the **setLatitude** method. Actually your **setLatitude** does not have any return value. On the other hand, the AJAX request runs asynchronously, which means that at the time your **success** callback is called your **createMap** method has already been called, with **undefined** as the value of **la** field. The simplest solution is to add **async: false** to your ajax call, like this:

```
function setLatitude(){
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'geo-data',
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
           result = data['latitude'];
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Or move calling of the method **createMap** to the **success** callback.

Comment: Sorry to reply late. It does work!  Thank you very much!